# How to purify/clean the tap water without using filter/purifier

Tags: personal-care, water, home

In the house, we're just drinking water straight from the tap/faucet.
But i'm worried, that after years, the pipe from the tap will get dirt and it will also affect the water coming from it.

Boiling water will eat a lot of time. So I don't like this way.

Perhaps, is there any way? In a natural way.

Comment: Where do you live? In much of the Western world, the tap water system is designed to produce drinkable water. E.g. pipes must be made of copper because it's a safe material.

Comment: Methods of water purification are outside the scope of this site. If you have concerns about the health/quality/taste of your water, you should seek a professional who can test your water and advise on the removal of specific contaminants they may find. But if you're looking for remediation or repair, you may want to have a look a our [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com) community and ask your question in the context of that site.